# D3 Chart with coloured zones background

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Can we create exactly the following chart in d3.js?

I have tried d3.arc but don't know how to create curved lines regions. Is there a way to create exactly like the image? P.S. I don't want to use an [image]image a background

Comment: It looks like perhaps a contour plot generated either with [d3](https://observablehq.com/@d3/contours) or [Plot](https://observablehq.com/plot/marks/contour) might do it. It really depends on your input, though.

Comment: Please post what you have tried; I'd expect at least the logarithmic axes and the `d3.arc` attempts to be working so one can debug it into something similar to your image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.